# XML transform copy one element twice in different section

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, transformation

I have a XML which needs some transformation to be properly imported to our database. I made most of the changes but I have a problem with duplicating of one element (E100customerKey in ApprovedCountry tag). No idea how can I duplicate it in this part of file. Please see code below:

Sample code received from partner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomerList>
    <TransferHeader>
        <Apllication>ApllicationForTransferCustomer</Apllication>
        <Sender>Partenr</Sender>
        <MailAdr>mail@mail.pl</MailAdr>
        <GeneratedDate>20160114</GeneratedDate>
        <NumberOfCustomers>3</NumberOfCustomers>
    </TransferHeader>
    <CustomerList>
        <Customer>
            <E100customerKey>03-98</E100customerKey>
            <VATNumber>2222222222</VATNumber>
            <EUVATNumber>11111111111</EUVATNumber>
            <CustomerName1>CustomerName</CustomerName1>
            <LineOfBusiness>uslugi transportowe</LineOfBusiness>
            <NACEcode>4941</NACEcode>
            <RequiredForPrivateCompany/>
            <ApprovedCountriesList>
                <ApprovedCountry>
                    <CountryCode>ES</CountryCode>
                    <ServiceType>Normal</ServiceType>
                    <PartnerPercent>3</PartnerPercent>
                </ApprovedCountry>
            </ApprovedCountriesList>
        </Customer>
    </CustomerList>
</CustomerList>
```

Needed code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomerList>
    <CustomerList>
        <Customer>
            <E100customerKey>03-98</E100customerKey>
            <VATNumber>2222222222</VATNumber>
            <EUVATNumber>11111111111</EUVATNumber>
            <CustomerName1>CustomerName</CustomerName1>
            <LineOfBusiness>uslugi transportowe</LineOfBusiness>
            <NACEcode>4941</NACEcode>
            <ApprovedCountriesList>
                <ApprovedCountry>
                    <E100customerKey>03-98</E100customerKey>
                    <CountryCode>ES</CountryCode>
                    <ServiceType>Normal</ServiceType>
                    <PartnerPercent>3</PartnerPercent>
                </ApprovedCountry>
            </ApprovedCountriesList>
        </Customer>
    </CustomerList>
</CustomerList>
```

My XSL file so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<!-- Probably needs to fix this part -->
 <xsl:template match="CustomerList/CustomerList/Customer/ApprovedCountriesList/ApprovedCountry">
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="CustomerList/TransferHeader|RequiredForPrivateCompany"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your output does not match the input - e.g. there is no `<ZipCode>21-400</ZipCode>` in the input or in your XSLT.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes you are right, I wanted to trim XML to delete unnecesarry information. Edited question to so now they should match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TransferHeader | RequiredForPrivateCompany"/>

<xsl:template match="ApprovedCountry">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../../E100customerKey"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. If I would like to change name of duplicated tag what should change in the instruction?